# SQL drop connection is similar with set single user command?

Tags: sql-server-2017

Would like to ask when i detach a database , i select the drop connection properties in the box. Is this drop connection properties is similar function as "set single user with rollback immediate"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>NOTE: You should update your question and tags to reflect which database engine and tools you are using, and their versions. I'm assuming from your description that you are using MS SQL Server, and SSMS to access it.</sup>

To answer the specific question: I believe so, yes.

In SSMS you can usually ask it to present the script it will run to carry out an operation, instead of running it, so you can record this, modify it, integrate it with other steps if a prices you are building, and do forth. You'll find a “script” button near the top of the detach database dialogue box that performs this task. For this and similar questions you can generate the script with the option selected and again without, and see *exactly* what difference it makes to what gets run in either case.

Comment: Thanks you, help a lot. But where can i find the record things? i am using SQL 2017

Comment: By "record" I was meaning save the script in your records.

Comment: Ok, totally get what your means. Thank you very much